# List of types from a function type

Tags: idris

I would like to make a function that given a function type (e.g. `String -> Nat -> Bool`), would return a list of types corresponding to that function type (e.g. `[String, Nat, Bool]`). Presumably the signature of such a function would be `Type -> List Type`, but I am struggling to determine how it would be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it could be done in general, because you cannot patter-match on functions. Neither can you check for the type of a function. That is not what dependent types are about. Just like in Haskell or OCaml the only thing you can actually do with a function is apply it to some argument. However, I devised some trick which might do:

```
myFun : {a, b : Type} -> (a -> b) -> List Type
myFun {a} {b} _ = [a, b]
```

Now the problem is that `a -> b` is the only signature that would match any arbitrary function. But, of course it does not behave the way you'd like for functions with arity higher than one:

```
> myFun (+)
[Integer, Integer -> Integer] : List Type
```

So some sort of recursive call to itself would be necessary to extract more argument types:

```
myFun : {a, b : Type} -> (a -> b) -> List Type
myFun {a} {b} _ = a :: myFun b
```

The problem here is that `b` is an arbitrary type, not necessarily a function type and there is no way I can figure out to dynamically check whether it is a function or not, so I suppose this is as much as you can do with Idris.

However, dynamic checking for types (at least in my opinion) is not a feature to be desired in a statically typed language. After all the whole point of static typing is to *specify in advance* what kind of arguments a function can handle and *prevent calling functions with invalid arguments* at compile time. So basically you probably don't really need it at all. If you specified what you grander goal was, someone would likely have shown you the right way of doing it.

Comment: Also note that calling `myFun` with `(+)` rendered somewhat strangely that its type is `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`, which is not really true. Basically, however, there is no way that function could behave propely for polymorphic functions at all.

Comment: Turns out it's possible in the prototype for the next iteration of Idris, codename Blodwen (https://github.com/edwinb/Blodwen), which allows pattern matching on types. But alas, it's not possible in Idris 1.